# 3-level Expandale Listview shows error in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to show a 3 level Expandable listview. I have made Adapter but I don't know if the values are being popuated correctly beacuse when I click on the group item, the app crashes and shows LogCat error:

```
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709): Process: com.example.pdt, PID: 22709
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.model.Model_Search_Group cannot be cast to com.example.model.Model_Search_Child
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at com.example.ListAdapter.ExpListAdapter$SecondLevelAdapter.getGroupView(ExpListAdapter.java:228)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2257)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at com.example.ListAdapter.ExpListAdapter$CustExpListview.onMeasure(ExpListAdapter.java:147)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16525)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1870)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1349)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1608)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2089)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-17 14:57:05.327: E/AndroidRuntime(22709):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
```

Adapter is :

```
public class ExpListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Model_Search_Group> groups;

public ExpListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model_Search_Group> groups) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.groups = groups;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<Model_Search_Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition)
            .getChildItems();
    return chList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    CustExpListview SecondLevelexplv = new CustExpListview(context);
    SecondLevelexplv.setAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter());
    SecondLevelexplv.setGroupIndicator(null);
    return SecondLevelexplv;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<Model_Search_Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition)
            .getChildItems();
    return chList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groups.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Model_Search_Group group = (Model_Search_Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.activity_search_group_row, null);
    }
    TextView edtTxtRef = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.edtTxtRef);
    TextView edtTxtName = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.edtTxtName);
    TextView edtTxtPrice = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.edtTxtPrice);
    edtTxtRef.setText(group.getItemRef());
    edtTxtName.setText(group.getName());
    edtTxtPrice.setText(group.getPrice());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

public class CustExpListview extends ExpandableListView {

    int intGroupPosition, intChildPosition, intGroupid;

    public CustExpListview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(960,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(600,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public class SecondLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Model_Search_Child child = (Model_Search_Child) getChild(
                groupPosition, childPosition);

        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.activity_search_child_row, null);

        TextView edtTxtSize = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.edtTxtSize);
        edtTxtSize.setText(child.getSize().toString());


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        ArrayList<Model_Search_Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition)
                .getChildItems();
        return chList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Model_Search_Child child = (Model_Search_Child)    
 getGroup(groupPosition);

        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.activity_search_child_row, null);
        TextView edtTxtColor = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.edtTxtColor);
        edtTxtColor.setText(child.getColor().toString());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}

}
```

In my MAinActivity:

```
    public void showList() {
    try {

        if (ExpListItems.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity_Search.this, "No Results",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter = new ExpListAdapter(Activity_Search.this,
                        ExpListItems);
                searchList.setAdapter(adapter);
                searchList
                        .setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() 
{

                            @Override
                            public boolean onChildClick(
                                    ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                    long id) {
                                v.setBackgroundColor(0);
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                searchList
                        .setOnItemLongClickListener(new     
 OnItemLongClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onItemLongClick(
                                    AdapterView<?> parent, View childView,
                                    int flatPos, long id) {

                                long packedPosition = searchList
                                        .getExpandableListPosition(flatPos);
                                // get item ID's
                                int itemType = ExpandableListView

 .getPackedPositionType(packedPosition);
                                int groupPosition = ExpandableListView

 .getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition);
                                int childPosition = ExpandableListView

 .getPackedPositionChild(packedPosition);
                                // GROUP-item clicked
                                // if (itemType ==
                                // 
  ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP)
                                // {
                                // // ...
                                // onGroupLongClick(groupPosition);
                                // }

                                // CHILD-item clicked
                                // else
                                if (itemType == 
 ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                                    // ...
                                    String barcode = ExpListItems
                                            .get(groupPosition)
                                            .getChildItems()
                                            .get(childPosition)
                                            .getBarcode();
                                    System.out.println("barcode" + barcode);

                                     Bundle b = new Bundle();
                                      b.putString("Barcode", barcode);
                                      Intent i = new Intent(
                                                Activity_Search.this,

  Activity_Sales_Return.class); //gets the intent that called this intent
                                      i.putExtras(b);
                                      setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                                    finish();
                                      return true;
                                }
                                return false;

                            }

                        });
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.model.Model_Search_Group
> cannot be cast to com.example.model.Model_Search_Child
>
> com.example.ListAdapter.ExpListAdapter$SecondLevelAdapter.getGroupView(ExpListAdapter.java:228)

As you can see from the log:

In your `getGroupView()` method, you're trying to cast a `Model_Search_Group` object to `Model_Search_Child` one.

This is why you have **ClassCastException** and your app crash.